# File format not recognized error in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, directory

I have been trying to open the contents of a directory  using the following code in c.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>

main(int *argc,char *argv[]){

DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d=opendir(*argv);
if(d){
while((dir = readdir(d))!= NULL){
printf("%s\n",dir->d_name);
}
closedir(d);
}

}
```

Then i execute the command like this:

```
gcc test.c ~/Desktop
```

but it returns something like this:

```
     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /home/cse-swlab5/Desktop: File format not recognized collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't find the reason.Also i have tried putting

`d=opendir("<path of the file here>");`

in that case the program works.Am i doing something wrong with passing arguments.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up compile time arguments and run time arguments. This should be two steps:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out ~/Desktop
```

There are a couple of other things wrong in the code. A working version is below:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <dirent.h>

// main should return int
// argc is an int, not a pointer to an int
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    //argv[0] is the program name,
    //argv[1] is what we want, but can only get it if it's there
    if (argc > 1) d=opendir(argv[1]);
    else return -1;

    if(d){
        while((dir = readdir(d))!= NULL){
            printf("%s\n",dir->d_name);
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, my initial problem is solved.But now on execution it terminates without giving any outputs.But Desktop contains several files.

Comment: I didn't look closely enough at this to diagnose the rest of your code. edit above.

Comment: Ok i got it Instead of `*argv` i gave `argv[1]`.My error with the pointers.Thanks @scf

Comment: glad you figured it out too, but make sure you add the error checking as I did above otherwise you will get a seg-fault if you try to run the program with no arguments.